# Setting Breakpoints in IDLE

Tags: python, breakpoints, python-idle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you add breakpoints to a python program in IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246878/how-do-you-add-breakpoints-to-a-python-program-in-idle)

How do you set a breakpoint at all in IDLE? There's no button anywhere!

Comment: OK. This search feature's horrible, and I couldn't find any relevant Windows results (there was a Mac one) using the question box. Now how do I mark this solved?

Comment: It looks like this question has been flagged by a few users for being a duplicate answer.  A moderator will take a look at it eventually, and redirect/close it for you :)