# How to stop at in IDLE breakpoint

Tags: python-3.x, breakpoints, python-idle

Running Python 3.3 on Win64, I found out how to add breakpoints in IDLE 3.3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246878/how-do-you-add-breakpoints-to-a-python-program-in-idle), but when I run my module via Run > Run Module (F5), it blows right through my breakpoints. What am I missing?

Comment: I got used to it and now I think these are for you, so that you can remember the line after you took a break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: The debugger checkbox]

You need to enable Debugging (check the Debug→Debugging checkbox from the Shell window). When you run the program, a dialog will show allowing you to control the execution code. If you select Go, it will  keep running your program until a breakpoint is reached.

Comment: Just to clarify this answer... I noticed that if you set a break point on an empty line, it will blow right through it. You have to set it on the first actual line of code that you don't want to run.