# Right Clicking isn't working for setting Breakpoints in IDLE. Did they change that feature?

Tags: python, debugging, breakpoints, python-idle

Right-clicking is not working to set breakpoints, no matter how many users say so. Did they remove or change the feature?

Comment: Please keep in mind stack overflow is for programming questions, not about the tools used in programming unless we are programming the tools themselves. You may have more luck over in [super user](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'.  On Windows 10, with 3.7.2, I just opened an editor window, right-clicked, selected Set breakpoint, and the breakpoint highlighting appeared as it should.  Of course, it will have no effect unless the debugger is turned on when the file is run.  I saved, closed, and reopened the file and the breakpoint was still set, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to press the debugger option in the Python Shell. Go to the `Debug` dropdown and press `Debugger`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23111746/10638232) for more info.